# Search all the Edgar Data from http://xbrl.sec.gov/

Tags: xbrl

I need to Fetch all the Edgar search data From xbrl site either in XML Format or in RSS Feed form.
This is the same Search on this Link http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/cik.htm which i want to create on my Website but donot want to use all the Data, just want to use a bit of Information in My Website.
And this is all the List of Items http://www.sec.gov/divisions/corpfin/organization/cfia.shtml
but don't know how to reach on a single Point.

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sec web site have lot of data, so have to first decide what information you want to get, mostly you would be interested in 10-Q and 10-K forms that contain financial statements.

Before 2010 information was submitted in html format and after words in html as well as XML (XBRL) files. This link http://www.sec.gov/divisions/corpfin/organization/cfia-c.htm gives all companies CIK's registered at sec, if you want information about a company you can use this URL :

http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=GOOG&type=&dateb=&owner=include&count=40

This will show all the filings from the company, you can change few parameters from this URL :

count : will return you number of files in a request

CIK : it can be CIK number or symbol for a company

type : this allow you to restrict the type of file you want, e.g `type=10-Q` will only return 10-Q documents for that company.

You can use any crawler to get html and xml files.

Also you can find all files from a company here :

http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/companyCIK